# What happens when I post an answer as a guest?

Tags: support, unregistered-users

If I want to answer a question when I am not logged in, I can post an answer as a guest on Stack Overflow. What happens when I do that? Does it mean I have created a new account on Stack Overflow?

Comment: Why didn't you ask this at [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com)?

Comment: I am a new user on SO and I don't have enough reputation to ask question on Meta SO. So I come here, and I could ask questions about all sites on StackExchange here. Could I?

Comment: @AlE That close reason (pertains to a specific site) doesn't apply here, since while the OP is on StackOverflow, the question itself pertains to the network as a whole.

Comment: *"So I come here, and I could ask questions about all sites on StackExchange here"* - Of course you can, but then please don't rollback the edits that adjust the question to use the proper tags.

Comment: @ChristianRau Sorry. I didn't notice that. I recover it now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you post as a guest, an account is created for you automatically and a cookie is placed on your computer, allowing you to use that account without having any other login method. (This is known as an *unregistered user*). There are a few things you can do with this new account, in particular:

1. Request it to be merged with your main one.
2. Register it by adding a login method. If you use the same login credential as for your main account, they should be merged automatically.
3. Delete the account by opening the user profile and clicking *delete* there.

Answer (score 2):

Third question:

> Another question, can I ask a question as guest?

[image: pic]

You can't post a question as a guest.

Comment: On SO, I can post an answer as a guest. You could try it.

Comment: @xshsinap Oh! I'm sorry. I didn't know that.